# FXML: An elegant way to bind a child width/height to the parent's width/height

Tags: javafx, fxml

I'm using FXML with JavaFX to develop graphical interfaces.  I discovered this method for binding the width/height of a child node to the width/height of it's parent node:

```
<Node fx:id="parent">
    <children>
        <Node prefWidth=${parent.width}></Node>
    <children>
</Node>
```

But that feels inelegant.  I'd rather not have to give an id to a node just so it's child can reference it's dimensions.  Is there perahps some method for referenceing the `parent` of a node?  Maybe something like `prefWidth=${parent.width}`?

NOTE:  I know this can be done programmatically from Java, but that's not what I want here.  I'm looking for a way to do this in the FXML.

Comment: [Expression bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#expression_binding) are resolved relative to the `FXMLLoader` namespace. Consequently you need to place some root of the expression into the namespace for this to work; the only way to do this in FXML is using an `fx:id`, as you do in the code snippet. So this is essentially as elegant as you can make this. Note that nodes have a `parent` property, so you should be able to do `<Node fx:id="node" prefWidth="${node.parent.width}"/>`, but this is arguably no better, at best.

Comment: I guess it's also worth pointing out that you would typically accomplish this functionality without binding anything, but by using an appropriate layout pane with the correct configuration. E.g. if using a `VBox` for the parent, set `fillWidth="true"` and make sure the `maxWidth` is unbounded on the child, etc.

Comment: Oh, so you *can* refer to the parent of the node.  That is much better, because then the code is portable.  Is there an equivalent of `this` in FXML, so I can call something like `this.parent.width`?  Or do I still need to give the inner node an ID?

Comment: No, again, everything is relative to the [namespace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#variable_resolution) of the `FXMLLoader`, so if `this` were valid (it's not) it would probably refer to the namespace, not the "current node". I haven't tested the `${node.parent.width}` idea, btw, but I think it should work.

Comment: If you want to place the info above into an answer I'll accept it.  The fact that there is no concept of `this` due to the `FXMLLoader` namespace, but that you *can* use the `parent` keyword in the FXML.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Expression bindings work by referencing elements of the `FXMLLoader`'s [namespace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#variable_resolution). There is no concept of "`this`" to refer to "the current node" (that I am aware of). So the only way to access the parent of a node is for the node itself to be part of the namespace: you can achieve this by setting an `fx:id` on the node itself:

```xml
<Pane>
    <children>
        <Node fx:id="node" prefWidth="${node.parent.width}"></Node>
    <children>
</Pane>
```